# Can custom icons be used with Blueprintjs components?

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons, blueprintjs

I'm considering using [Blueprintjs](http://blueprintjs.com/) in an application.

Is it possible to use custom SVG icons in the [button](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/button), [menu](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/menu) and [navbar](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/navbar) components? All the examples I've seen use the [built-in icon set](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/icons).

The app I'm developing would rely heavily on custom icons so being restricted to the built-in set wouldn't work.

Seems like it would be an obvious thing to be able to do, so I presume I'm just not finding the samples. If anyone could point me to some, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Custom icons are currently unsupported in the core components. You should follow this issue for future updates that might enable support for this kind of use case: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/365